# why does my internet go down when running openvpn?

Tags: vpn, centos5, windows

We are trying to put a openvpn server in our network. while we are testing, when the openvpn service is running, all other computers on the same network as the server lose internet connectivity. Any ideas would be very helpful. thanks.

Comment: Is your openvpn server also serving as a router/NAT for the rest of your network?

Comment: no its not the only thing thats configured on the router is the forwarding of the port 1149 to the vpn server.

Comment: Well then you're going to need to provide more information about what exactly you mean by "lose internet connectivity". Are hosts able to ping the router? Past the router? Are hosts able to resolve DNS names? Have you done a packet capture to see precisely what's going on?

Comment: host cannot ping the gateway's ip or hostname. so it wont even let packets out of our network let alone our gateway.

Comment: i cant run a packet capture because without the internet the sales team loses leads and money and the hire ups are sticklers about internet connectivity

Comment: It's going to be impossible for us to give you any help without more information.

Answer (score 0):

Two quick suggestions.

1. Doublecheck your server settings and make sure that the OpenVPN stuff doesn't pickup and start using the router's IP.
2. Doublecheck your ports and DHCP settings to make sure that OpenVPN isn't taking DHCP away from another internal server or your router and stranding your PCs with a bad gateway.

Comment: ok i will check